# Saving and Deleting Files Properly - Android

Tags: android

I have an Android (API 26) application that downloads files, saves them to the device storage, opens them in their respective application and deletes them after they are done being viewed.  My problem is with the Android file system.

To create the file, I use:

```
File localFile = 
new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)) 
+ File.separator 
+ GlobalSettings.getTempFolderName() 
+ File.separator 
+ file.getName());
// resolves to: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Temp/0500-001.pdf

if (!localFile.exists())
{
    localFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    localFile.createNewFile();
}
```

When I go to delete the same file, I use:

```
File fileToDelete = new File(path);
// path resolves to /storage/emulated/0/Download/Temp/0500-001.pdf    

if (fileToDelete.exists())
    test = fileToDelete.delete();
```

The problem I have is Android is creating a copy of the file that I can only see via Windows' File Explorer when the device is connected to my PC via USB.  At the path `PC\ET5X\Internal storage\Download\Temp` in File Explorer I see the 0500-001.pdf file, even after deleting it using the code above.  I cannot find this file with the Android file explorer (even performing a search from root level) or even ES File Explorer.  I can't have a bunch of files taking up storage.. they must be deleted after they are viewed.

How can I save and delete files without Android making a duplicate, or how can I delete the duplicate as well?

Comment: If you deleted the file then the file is gone. But the MediaStore can still hold a reference to it. That reference is what you see on your pc. Try to download it on your pc and you will see that it will not do. Reboot your device and the reference has gone.

Comment: You are right! Thanks for the information. I tried downloading the file onto my PC and it totally crashed my PC (nice one Windows).